# Force Web View On Mobile Screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Have anyone tried forcing desktop view to display on mobile devices (when one clicks the view desktop version on their browsers)?

I was thinking if it is possible to maintain normal mobile view for mobile and then force desktop view when the view desktop version is selected on mobile devices...

Answer (score 1):

The 'View Desktop Version' button present in google chrome browsers works this way:

- It changes the `User-Agent` header in the request to match those
  sent by the desktop browsers.
- It ignores the original viewport meta tag and applies the default
  "min-width: 980px;" media query to the `css` thus putting the responsive
  pages into their desktop layout.

So if your website is responsive then there is no need to do any extra work. It will automatically switch to the desktop layout when forced through 'View Desktop Version'.